# How to remotely connect to Ubuntu 18.04 with UI and keeping locked screen?

Tags: vnc, remote, vncviewer, remote-login

How to remotly connect to Ubuntu 18.04 with UI, with the following conditions:

1. Be able to login remotely even if no local session exists (eg.: after reeboot)
2. Keep locked screen in the phisical machine

- Tried Ubuntu Screen Sharing but it fails 1) and 2).
- Tried X11VNC, it solves 1) but fails 2).

Comment: I believe you'd have to start another session and connect to that or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have always used the application [TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com/en/download/linux) for this. I believe it meets all your criteria and is cross platform. To get it to work right after a reboot you will have to share your network with all users so you do not need to be signed in.

Edit:
I apologize, I misread requirement 2. You can not keep a lock screen on the host monitor while running, although I believe it has a feature to black out the host monitor if that helps in your situation

Comment: Shouldn't you be suggesting the Linux version? https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/ If so, lpease [edit] your answer

Comment: Installed teamviewer in ubuntu, it solves 1) but fails 2). Can you explain how to do the configuration to share the network? Thanks

Comment: I don't think the "share the network" is relevant unless your remote computer is connected to the local network by WiFi. If the computer uses WiFi to connect, make sure that specific WiFi connection is "available to other users" of that computer, even it you are the only user. This ensures the WiFi connection is made at boot time instead of after you login.

Comment: I have always used it with WiFi. Thought you would need to share LAN too

Answer (score 0):

I thik **XRDP** solves this task.
https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp
for me it worked
to install it you can run

```
apt install xrdp xorgxrdp
```

After installing it, you can connect to it form windows with **mstsc** or any other RDP client on linux, if you use linux.

Also a solution can bee **x11vnc**
x11vnc is a VNC server that is not dependent on any one particular graphical environment. Also, it facilitates using in a minimal environment, as it has a tcl/tk based GUI. It can be started while your computer is still showing a login screen.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you could give more details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).